# SSRS Temporary table issue, data from stored procedure which include dynamic pivot. (SQL 2008/Visual Studio 2008)

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008

I have a stored procedur which runs ok from SQL level but when I am tryning to 
add dataset in SSRS there is an issue with temp table. I know that SSRS has a problem with temp tables (in my case global table) but how can I resolve this problem? I saw few solutions suggests to create @table but how can I do that with data from dynamic pivot and I am not sur of it reaaly works?

Here is  example of my dynamic pivot:

DECLARE @PmtCols_pwyk AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query_pwyk AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
select @PmtCols_pwyk = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(przerwa) 
                    from #przerwa_wyk
                    group by przerwa
                    order by przerwa
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')

if OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..##pwyk_po_pivocie') is not null drop table ##pwyk_po_pivocie
set @query_pwyk = 'SELECT Id_Pracownika,' + @PmtCols_pwyk + ' into ##pwyk_po_pivocie from 
             (select przerwa, Id_Pracownika, przerwa_wyk from #przerwa_wyk ) as x
            PIVOT 
            (max(przerwa_wyk) for przerwa in (' + @PmtCols_pwyk + ')) as p'
execute(@query_pwyk) ;

Comment: Why don't you do pivot using MATRIX of SSRS? All you need is to have your data put in 3 columns: Id_Pracownika, col_name, col_val

Comment: I need all data in one table is the most important reason, (and few more). I'll be appreciate for solution based on sql not matrix in SSRS.

Comment: SSRS expects the column names top be the same every time the dataset query executes so if you column names change then it won't work. I'm not sure I understand why you can't can't use a Matrix, it would make your query simpler too. The data is still in one table, it's just the dataset output structure would be different and you wouldn't need your global temp table ether.

Comment: >>>I need all data in one table<<< And where did I sy you'll not have it in 1 table? I said, your input data should be in one table (3 colums), and the result will be still 1 table, without any dynamic code. All you need is to put  Id_Pracownika as rows, col_name as columns and col_val as body. The matrix will have as many columns as distinct col_name exists

Comment: I need to clarify, dynamic pivot's is only a part of bigger query, I have a lots of data which I join in one big table. The specific data, variables etc. causes that I need it in one table. I showed You the piece of code which aare making issue, so please I dont' need another answer "use ssrs matrix' I need procedure :)

Comment: Does your procedure produce the table of fixed structure? I mean, do you know the number of columns of the result table? is it always the same?

Comment: It is one table but, every day number of columns and rows could be different. First 27 columns wiil be alaways static, last 5-11 colums could be dynamic depend on which day query starts. Number of rows evry day will be different. I think there is a way to make one static number of columns, I am quite sure that max number of clolumns (dynamic) will never cross the 11 so I could create static tabel.